# tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex: for table footer/header

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Hey,
Any clever way to jump to table header or footer with section indices? What I want is to add a section index at the top of the indices that jumps to header and another one at the bottom that brings you to footer without having to scroll.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following method on `UITableView` to scroll to the correct index path:
`- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated`.

Use the `+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSUInteger)row inSection:(NSUInteger)section` method on `NSIndexPath` to generate an index path to each section start by setting the row to 0 and the section runs from 0 to the total number of sections, which can be asked from the data source.

Comment: Actually yeah, it is dead simple. Returning -1 to tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex: and performing scrollToRowAtIndexPath on relevant index does the job very well.